# Filtering a grid with an OData Enum as a field

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to filter a grid datasource with an enum field.

It seems that the OData api has deprecated / removed the ability to have handle prefix free Enums on the server side.

I am adding the following to the grid's filter.

```
let fd1: FilterDescriptor = {
  field: 'orderStatus',
  operator: 'eq',
  value: "SOPSModel.OrderStatusEnum'Open'",
  ignoreCase: false
}
this.filter.filters.push(fd1);
```

The issue seems to be that the toOdataString function provided in kendo-data-query identifies the Enum as a string and then quotes and escapes it, which makes the server side API rejects the enum and fails.

I set up my own filter parser, which worked ok, but with the new filtering options that have been added to the Grid I really need a proper solution to this.

So, can anybody point me in the direction of how Telerik inteded OData Enums to be handled?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish to change the transport parameter map using this example:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.parametermap

Something like:

```
dataSource: {
    type: "odata-v4",
    transport: {
        read: {
            dataType: "json",
            url: datasourceURL          
        },            
        parameterMap: function (data, type) {               
            var c = kendo.data.transports["odata-v4"].parameterMap(data, type);


// transform your c exactly how you wish to make the call to the service and put it on a string

return c; 
}
```